# VBA Syntax Error If string variable equals "a" or "b" or "c"

Tags: string, function, vba, variables

I'm trying to write code that does the following in VBA but i get error: Type mismatch

Quark is a string variable

```
 If quark = "F" Or "DE" Or "ED" Then
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each "OR" is its own boolean statement.

```
If quark = "F" Or quark ="DE" Or quark ="ED" Then
```

You could acheive what you are trying to do with a case though I think

```
Select Case quark 
Case "F","DE","ED" 
     stuffHere
end select
```

EDIT:
I see that you were getting a type mismatch, did you dim quark as a string?

```
dim quark as string
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try like to compare like this:-

```
If quark = "F" Or quark = "DE" Or quark = "ED" Then
```

instead of:-

```
If quark = "F" Or "DE" Or "ED" Then
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare quark to the strings.

```
If quark = "F" Or quark = "DE" Or quark = "ED" Then
```